# Does Apple have a public policy on what it will allow governments to scan their citizen's iPhones for?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, security, privacy

Apple [announced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQUO1DSwYN0) that the [iPhone will soon scan photos on the device](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2021/08/apples-plan-think-different-about-encryption-opens-backdoor-your-private-life) to look for nefarious content. As users update their iOS, this feature will soon be on [all 1bn+ iPhones in every country](https://edwardsnowden.substack.com/p/all-seeing-i)<sup>1</sup>.

The first use of this new feature is to scan photos of US iPhones for child sexual abuse material (CSAM). But it isn't clear what future uses it has, particularly outside the US, and especially in countries whose governments are not tolerant of political dissent, LGBTQ, women's rights, and other "illegal" activities.

#### Question

Has Apple released a policy paper detailing how it will work with governments to decide what to scan for, and if there are any limits it places on what Governments can request that Apple scan for?

#### Example

Suppose a meme was created mocking a Russian or Chinese political leader; and the respective governments asked Apple to scan iPhones for that meme to find out who else may have shared it or even who created it - is there some policy document available so we can know in advance whether Apple would automatically comply?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On iPhones using iOS15 and which back up photos to iCloud ([~85% of all iPhones](https://edwardsnowden.substack.com/p/all-seeing-i)).</sub>

Comment: One should always operate under the assumption that big brother is watching you and act accordingly! One should just not do anytime that would get one into an unwanted situation, then one has nothing to worry about! :)

Comment: @user3439894 I know you mean well. But it's not always possible. Random example, for gay people from [countries in which it's illegal to be gay](https://www.humandignitytrust.org/lgbt-the-law/map-of-criminalisation/) they could have to delete photos with their partner, which is horrible. But as you allude to, possibly preferable to what their government would do if their private photos are exposed. I am specifically interested in knowing how such people can figure out if they're at risk - a public policy from Apple would help them to understand.

Comment: This is the company that forced America's FBI to go to the highest court in the land to try persuade them to unlock a phone of a suspected terrorist. Apple refused, point-blank, citing 'privacy'. If they won't bow to that in their own country, I doubt they would ever bow to any other government request.

Comment: The title of this needs rework IMO. Can you make this into a practical problem as opposed to a hypothetical. As announced this is a partnership between Apple and one specific NGO. If you are looking for the page where Apple has announced this that is answerable, but we can’t speak for what isn’t released publicly.

Comment: @tetsujin OTOH they seem to be quite flexible in China, so Apple‘s options may be tightly linked with whatever national laws allow.

Comment: @nohillside that's right. All of China's iCloud data is stored on Chinese Government owned servers. And a reminder that that data is not end to end encrypted - it is encrypted at rest but it can be unencrypted by Apple any time. So implicitly, Apple have already given Chinese government access to Chinese citizen's iCloud data, I think.

Comment: My how “outside the US” and government tolerance has aged…

Answer (score 3):

The CSAM scanning is not being done by a government agency.  Apple is working with The National Center for Missing & Exploited Children, a private non-profit group.

In their recently released [Expanded Protections for Children, Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.apple.com/child-safety/pdf/Expanded_Protections_for_Children_Frequently_Asked_Questions.pdf) paper, Apple stated:

> **Q: Could governments force Apple to add non-CSAM images to the hash list?**

> A: No. Apple would refuse such demands and our system has been designed to prevent that from  happening.  We have faced demands to build and deploy government-mandated changes that degrade the privacy of users before, and have steadfastly refused those demands. We will continue to refuse them in the future. Let us be clear, this technology is limited to detecting CSAM stored in iCloud and we will not accede to any government’s request to expand it.

With regard to scanning as indicated in your meme example, Apple only refers to their privacy policy regarding when they'll work with local governments on accessing a user's data.

As laws vary in each country, a person would need to reference their country's privacy policy to determine what rights they have in relation to their government.  It's not possible to point to a single comprehensive policy that covers everyone.

Comment: I think this is the best we can hope for in terms of an answer to this question, especially on this site.

Comment: Apple: "Let us be clear, we ***could*** turn our customers/users over to governments/law enforcement, but trust us, we won't do that unless they commit offenses that **WE** judge to be objectionable." Given that it's Apple, this *may be* the best we can hope for, but it's unacceptable. It's also insulting they would ask their customers to believe this.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, 8 Dec 2022, [Apple abandoned its plans to scan users photos for CSAM material](https://www.wired.com/story/apple-photo-scanning-csam-communication-safety-messages/):

> The tool was meant to be privacy-preserving and allow the company to flag potentially problematic and abusive content without revealing anything else. But the initiative was controversial, and it soon drew widespread criticism from privacy and security researchers and digital rights groups who were concerned that the surveillance capability itself could be abused to undermine the privacy and security of iCloud users around the world.

> At the beginning of September 2021, Apple said it would pause the rollout of the feature to “collect input and make improvements before releasing these critically important child safety features.” In other words, a launch was still coming. Now the company says that in response to the feedback and guidance it received, the CSAM-detection tool for iCloud photos is dead.