# CSAM scanning in IOS 15

Tags: ios, privacy

Does iOS 15 and 15.5 in particular have CSAM scanning? I've done a lot of internet searching and have not yet found a definitive answer.

Comment: If you could define what you consider to be CSAM scanning, this might get constructive answers. Have a look at our [tour] and [ask] for guidance on documenting your research. [Show us what you found and why it’s not helpful](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/426320/5472), ideally.

Answer (score 4):

iOS 15 has a feature for children under 13 that works in Messages only, and does not communicate results to anyone, including the parents. This feature can be enabled by the child's parents only.

It blurs images that it thinks could be explicit, and warns children both before sending and before opening them.

**iOS does NOT have any feature that scans the photo library of the device for explicit content, nor does it have any feature that reports the results externally.**

Source: https://www.apple.com/child-safety/ explains what **is** included. This page previously mentioned CSAM but they announced ([here](https://www.theverge.com/2021/12/15/22837631/apple-csam-detection-child-safety-feature-webpage-removal-delay) is an article) it is being postponed to address shortcomings. They have not re-released any information on it.